# urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request for Python3 Slack hook

Tags: python-3.x, urllib, slack, urlopen

Using Python3 at the command line repl:

What am I getting wrong in my request format?

I am getting

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

when I do

```
>>>> from urllib import request
>>>> import urllib.parse

>>> data = urllib.parse.urlencode({"channel": "#aws_lambda_python_int", "username": "webhookbot", "text": "This is posted to #aws_lambda_python_int and comes from a bot named webhookbot.", "icon_emoji": ":ghost:"})                                                                                   
>>> data_encoded = data.encode('ascii')
>>> with urllib.request.urlopen("https://hooks.slack.com/services/THGF2356K/BQC7FJZ52/d1Ary9idSP5AAAAAAAAAAAA", data_encoded) as f:                
...     print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
...
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 649, in http_error_default                                                                      
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing `urllib.parse.urlencode` with `json.dumps`.

```
>>> from urllib import request
>>> import json

>>> data = json.dumps({"channel": "#aws_lambda_python_int", "username": "webhookbot", "text": "This is posted to #aws_lambda_python_int and comes from a bot named webhookbot.", "icon_emoji": ":ghost:"})                                                                                   
>>> data_encoded = data.encode('ascii')
>>> with urllib.request.urlopen("https://hooks.slack.com/services/THGF2356K/BQC7FJZ52/d1Ary9idSP5AAAAAAAAAAAA", data_encoded) as f:                
...     print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
```